# CSS Definition list - move inline with unordered list

Tags: css, inline

I have an action bar that holds links. Each link is a `<li>` and the css sets `display:inline`.

However, one of the `<li>` is a `<dl><dt>`, and this item is not displayed inline.

You can see this demonstrated at http://jsfiddle.net/MAxMn/2/

What extra css do I need to include to move this the `<dl<dt>` item inline with the rest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.view-actions dl,dt {
    display: inline;
}
```

Comment: This works on the fiddle that I provided, but in my actual scenario it doesnt for some reason. I've linked the full css file at http://jsfiddle.net/MAxMn/5/

Comment: looks like you have display: block set within the stylesheet for any dt and span descending from the .view-actions class.  you can test or overwrite that with !important http://jsfiddle.net/MAxMn/6/.  if you want height and width, you may not want inline.  floats could be better.

Answer (score 0):

I updated it. Instead of putting `inline` I switched to `float:left`. I also added a br with a `clear:both` that will make sure that after the section after the div goes to the next line like it should.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MAxMn/4/)